# hive query and udf execution strategy

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I am curious as to how hive executes queries and in particular custom UDFs.  I have 4 datanodes, and thereby 4 task trackers on 4 different VMs.

The data on the datanodes are encrypted, and my UDF decrypts the data.  I am curious as to how hive executes this UDF, is it:

1) each task tracker retrieves whatever data is on its datanode, and decrypts it and returns it

2) the job tracker retrieves all encrypted data, then delegates the decryption to all 4 task trackers.

I hope my question is clear...